# Entity Framework schedule query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scheduler

I know that nhibernate has a scheduler that will execute a function at certain intervals. I was wanting this same functionality with EF.

So I want to send an email to a user a week after they were initially notified. Is there anyway to do this on the server, say check the db once a day and send out emails to everyone that meets the criteria?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Task Scheduler or a SQL Server Agent Job.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why would scheduling tasks be a function for an ORM?

Comment: I meant fluent instead of nhibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the fluent package and used the fluent scheduler to run queries at specific intervals.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a console application that does what you need and then use the Task Scheduler to run that application daily.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ for task scheduling